# How to properly update (add/update/remove) related data of entity (EF Core)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern

I have the following simplified models (configured with FluentAPI to working MS SQL tables):

```
CV:
   int ID
   string Title
   List<SkillCV> SkillsCVs // many-to-many junction/associative model/table to link the 2 tables

SkillCV:
   int CvID
   int SkillID
   bool IsCore

Skill:
   int ID
   string Title
```

I use repository pattern which is injected to a service which is injected in a API controller. So I will simplify the logic directly into a service method:

```
public async Task<int> UpdateAsync(CV cv)
{
   var cvDB = await context.Set<CV>()
               .Include(CV => CV.SkillsCVs)
                  .ThenInclude(skillCV => skillCV.Skill)
               .Include(CV => CV.User)
               .FirstOrDefaultAsync(CV => CV.Id == cv.Id);
   cvDB.Title = cv.Title;
   SkillCV[] skillsCVs = ...; // I get this with SemaphoreSlim, because it has concurrency issues with async lambda in LINQ method
   // assume that I have the "new" SkillCV array of entities that I need to replace the old ones with
   
   // cvDB.SkillsCVs = skillsCVs.ToList(); // many exceptions here
   UpdateSkills(cvDB, skillsCVs);
}
```

How to replace the old cvDB.SkillsCVs list with the new skillsCVs list? When both of the lists are equal (same entities with same values) I get "already atached skill with id..." exception. If the old cvDB.SkillsCVs array is empty, it adds the new entities without a problem. How to solve the problem with unchanged/removed states. I need a method that will update the list with a new list.

```
   public UpdateSkills(CV cv, List<SkillsCV> newSkillsCVs)
   {
      var oldSkillsCVs = cv.SkillsCVs;
      // how to replace oldSkillsCVs with newSkillsCVs
   }
```

Can you help me with this method? I have everything Included in the CV

Answer (score 0):

There must be a better way but what I can think right now,

```cs
if(cv.SkillsCVs != null || cv.SkillCVs.Count != 0)
   context.Entry(cv.SkillsCVs).State = EntityState.Detached;
     
cv.SkillsCVs = newSkillsCVs;
```

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'List<SkillCV>' was not found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model. Why is this happening? What am I missing?

Answer (score -1):

You should clear the collection cv.SkillsVCs and then fill it with newSkillsCVs:

```
cv.SkillsCVs.Clear();
cv.SkillsCVs.AddRange(newSkillsCVs);
```

Comment: Very bad idea - this would remove all skill rows from database and add new ones, while you only want to remove the removed skills and add new ones.

Comment: When I update it with `context.Set<CV>().Update(cv); await context.SaveChangesAsync();` it says: `System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'CV' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 8}'` but the CV I want to update has id 14

Comment: @Danny Varod: it removes only the SkillsCVs of the cv, not all the skill rows from database